# Can "like-this" be considered as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives

I'm just asking whether "like-this" can be considered as an adjective ?

example : we don’t see like-this opportunities all the time 
is this correct, if not, why ? and what to say instead ?

and Thanks !

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: "like-this" is not a recognised word, so even though in your sentence it is functioning as an adjective, the sentence itself is weird English. Why wouldn't you use the normal expression "we don't see opportunities like this all the time"? :-)

Comment: Or, "we don't see this kind of opportunity every day."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not believe this to be a legitimate compound word.

I would recommend "similar" to replace it, which is an adjective.

*"We don't see similar opportunities..."*

Or, for clarity if context doesn't provide it:
*"We don't see opportunities similar to this..."*

Answer (score 0):

re: What to say instead?

The adjective corresponding to *like* is ***such***:

> We don’t see **such** opportunities all the time.

However, the usual way is to place the modifying phrase **after the noun**, instead:

> We don’t see opportunities **like this** all the time.

HTH.